# while comparing the two objects in scala not getting correct result

Tags: scala, equals

Pojo classes

```
    case class RulePojoMigration(val tolerance_id:Int,val asset_id:Int, measure: String, cond: String, function: String, threshold_value: String, rule_dts: String,
                                     filter: util.List[Filter], is_enabled: String, mode: String, tolerance_status: String, action_key: String, 
                                     email_ids: util.List[String], rule_name:String, rule_owner:String, group_by: util.List[String], relax_variation_band:String, reconciliation_id:Int)
case class Filter(value: String, operator: String, dimension: String)
    Below is the code used to fetch the object from DB
    
    if (checkRuleIsEditOrNot) {
                        ps = con.prepareStatement(WSQueryConstant.RULE_MIGRATION_GET_COMPLETE_RULE_INFO_FROM_STAGE)
                        ps.setInt(1, rulePojo.tolerance_id)
                        rs = ps.executeQuery
    
                        var dbRulePojo: RulePojoMigration = null
                        val jsonRulePojo: RulePojoMigration = rulePojo
                        if (rs.next()) {
                            val rule_tolerance_asset_id = rs.getInt(2)
                            val measure = rs.getString(3)
                            val cond = rs.getString(4)
                            val function = rs.getString(5)
                            val threshold_value = rs.getString(6)
                            val rule_dts = rs.getString(7)
                            val filter = gson.fromJson(rs.getString(8), classOf[util.List[Filter]])
                            val is_enabled = rs.getString(9)
                            val mode = rs.getString(10)
                            val tolerance_status = rs.getString(11)
                            val email_ids = gson.fromJson(rs.getString(12), classOf[java.util.List[String]])
                            val rule_name = rs.getString(13)
                            val rule_owner = rs.getString(14)
                            val group_by = gson.fromJson(rs.getString(15), classOf[java.util.List[String]])
                            val relax_variation_band = rs.getString(16)
                            var reconciliation_id = rs.getString(17)
                            if(reconciliation_id== null)
                                 reconciliation_id= "-1"
                            dbRulePojo = RulePojoMigration(jsonRulePojo.tolerance_id, rule_tolerance_asset_id, measure, cond, function, threshold_value, rule_dts, filter, is_enabled, mode, tolerance_status, jsonRulePojo.action_key, email_ids, rule_name, rule_owner, group_by, relax_variation_band, reconciliation_id.toInt)
```

1. user request with the below values.

   RulePojoMigration(1274,1234,*,less than,count,100,2020-07-04 05:31:29,**[Filter(Hello,equal,funnel_state)]**,1,static,null,EMAIL,[x],StaticRuleMigrationTesting,email,[ALL],0,-1)
2. Object available in MySQL database

   RulePojoMigration(1274,1234,*,less than,count,100,2020-07-04 05:31:29,**[{value=Hello, operator=equal, dimension=funnel_state}]**,1,static,null,EMAIL,[x],StaticRuleMigrationTesting,email,[ALL],0,-1)

So I want to check the equality of two objects so that the user can modify the the existing object if there is any changes in the payload or simply he/she should get a message saying duplicate entry exist. `jsonRulePojo.equal(dbRulePojo)` should be true, anyhow values are same of both object.

Comment: Please use Scala coding/naming conventions

Answer (score 3):

The default `equals` operation does not check the contents of the two classes, it just checks whether both values *refer to the same object*. So two instances of `RulePojoMigration` will always be different even if every field is the same. By default two classes are only equal if they are the same instance.

When a `case class` is defined, Scala will generate an `equals` that does check each of the fields passed to the constructor in turn. So two `case classe`s will be equal if they have the same contents.

So you can fix this code in one of two ways:

1. Make `RulePojoMigration` a `case class`
2. Add an `equals` method to `RulePojoMigration`

Comment: It's already a case class, I have forgotten to add here. @Tim

Comment: Can anyone help me to resolve the problem, now I have already overridden the equals method but still not working?

Comment: @user Yes, indeed I did. I've edited the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I am able to resolve the bug by making the below changes.

```
From
val filter = gson.fromJson(rs.getString(8), classOf[util.List[Filter]]) 
To 
 val filter = gson.fromJson(rs.getString(8), classOf[Array[Filter]])
```

and

```
dbRulePojo = RulePojoMigration(jsonRulePojo.tolerance_id, rule_tolerance_asset_id, measure, cond, function, threshold_value, rule_dts, java.util.Arrays.asList(filter:_*)
                            , is_enabled, mode, tolerance_status, jsonRulePojo.action_key, email_ids, rule_name, rule_owner, group_by, relax_variation_band, reconciliation_id.toInt)
```

And instead of passing the `filter` directly into `dbRulePojo` i passed the `java.util.Arrays.asList(filter:_*)`